# Is there an R function that will remove the last value of each row?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that contains the steps a consumer took on their way to make a purchase and a value showing how much each step was worth. I want to get rid of the last value in each row to look at how much non last steps helped.  I need help replacing or sub setting out those values.

This data is of varying lengths and has many different values:

```
My data looks somewhat like this. 

df <- data.frame(
  weight_1 = c(43L, 2L, 6L, 30L, 69L, 82L, 98L, 79L, 68L),
  weight_2 = c(60L, 40L, 78L, 48L, 75L, 77L, 55L, 3L, 66L),
  weight_3 = c(22L, 4L, 77L, 40L, 91L, 57L, 34L, 84L, NA),
  weight_4 = c(88L, 47L, 77L, 82L, 31L, 19L, 11L, NA, NA),
  weight_5 = c(80L, 65L, 12L, 17L, 62L, 95L, NA, NA, NA),
  weight_6 = c(95L, 71L, 14L, 29L, 66L, 83L, NA, NA, NA),
  weight_7 = c(64L, 20L, 69L, 57L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  weight_8 = c(45L, 19L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

I have found the last row value using

```
final_row <- as.data.frame(df[cbind( 1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df),"last") )])
colnames(final_row)[1] <- "last_value"
```

Now I'm just looking for a way to delete those values from the dataset so I can look at non last step values.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a sample of your data using `dput()` and sharing it as part of your question in order to make it reproducible. Off-hand, I'd say that you need to add an id variable to keep track of respondents using `row_number()`, then pivot the data into long format using `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package, then remove the `NAs` with `drop_na()`, and then filter out whichever row has the last value with `filter()`. But again, it would be easier to show how with actual data to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace last non-NA value in each row with `NA` you can use `apply` in base R -

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
             x[max(which(!is.na(x)))] <- NA
             x
       }))
```

Answer (score 2):

You perhaps want this?

```r
df <- data.frame(
  weight_1 = c(43L, 2L, 6L, 30L, 69L, 82L, 98L, 79L, 68L),
  weight_2 = c(60L, 40L, 78L, 48L, 75L, 77L, 55L, 3L, 66L),
  weight_3 = c(22L, 4L, 77L, 40L, 91L, 57L, 34L, 84L, NA),
  weight_4 = c(88L, 47L, 77L, 82L, 31L, NA, 19L, 11L, NA),
  weight_5 = c(80L, 65L, 12L, 17L, 62L, NA, 40L, 95L, NA),
  weight_6 = c(95L, 71L, 14L, NA, 29L, NA, 66L, 83L, NA),
  weight_7 = c(64L, 20L, NA, NA, 69L, NA, 57L, NA, NA),
  weight_8 = c(45L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19L, NA, NA)
)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(cur_column() == names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = 'last')], NA, .)))
#>   weight_1 weight_2 weight_3 weight_4 weight_5 weight_6 weight_7 weight_8
#> 1       43       60       22       88       80       95       64       NA
#> 2        2       40        4       47       65       71       NA       NA
#> 3        6       78       77       77       12       NA       NA       NA
#> 4       30       48       40       82       NA       NA       NA       NA
#> 5       69       75       91       31       62       29       NA       NA
#> 6       82       77       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
#> 7       98       55       34       19       40       66       57       NA
#> 8       79        3       84       11       95       NA       NA       NA
#> 9       68       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

earlier answer

```r
df <- data.frame(
    weight_1 = c(43L, 2L, 6L, 30L, 69L, 82L, 98L, 79L, 68L),
    weight_2 = c(60L, 40L, 78L, 48L, 75L, 77L, 55L, 3L, 66L),
    weight_3 = c(22L, 4L, 77L, 40L, 91L, 57L, 34L, 84L, NA),
    weight_4 = c(88L, 47L, 77L, 82L, 31L, NA, 19L, 11L, NA),
    weight_5 = c(80L, 65L, 12L, 17L, 62L, NA, 40L, 95L, NA),
    weight_6 = c(95L, 71L, 14L, NA, 29L, NA, 66L, 83L, NA),
    weight_7 = c(64L, 20L, NA, NA, 69L, NA, 57L, NA, NA),
    weight_8 = c(45L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19L, NA, NA)
      )

df
#>   weight_1 weight_2 weight_3 weight_4 weight_5 weight_6 weight_7 weight_8
#> 1       43       60       22       88       80       95       64       45
#> 2        2       40        4       47       65       71       20       NA
#> 3        6       78       77       77       12       14       NA       NA
#> 4       30       48       40       82       17       NA       NA       NA
#> 5       69       75       91       31       62       29       69       NA
#> 6       82       77       57       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
#> 7       98       55       34       19       40       66       57       19
#> 8       79        3       84       11       95       83       NA       NA
#> 9       68       66       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  summarise(last_col = last(na.omit(c_across(everything()))), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   last_col
#>      <int>
#> 1       45
#> 2       20
#> 3       14
#> 4       17
#> 5       69
#> 6       57
#> 7       19
#> 8       83
#> 9       66
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I already found the last values (sorry if that wasn't clear), but this is another excellent example of how to find them. I'm looking to replace or filter out the last value once found.

Comment: @JeffRowley, see revised answer